Server Not updating the data even though it is updated in the json file
So, I am using react and node to build a website and when testing locally it worked fine ,but once i hosted it on VPS, it doesnt seem to be working. For example when I send a feedback from the feedback page, the feedback.json in the server is updated but on the admin panel, in feedback section the new feedback doesnot appear.
At first it showed the 304 Not Modified, then i used Cache-control for no cache
This is my code in the index.js for the backend
app.get('/api/getfeedbacks', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    res.json(feedbacks);
});

useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/getfeedbacks')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            setFeedbackMessage(data);
        });
}, []);

